# JSON output in array using PHP explode

Tags: php, html, json, decode, explode

So, I have an output from an API using JSON:

```
{"listings":[{"adoption_fee":"$200","adoption_process":"For cats, please fill out our \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/pre-adoption-form-cats/\"\u003ePre-Adoption Questionnaire - Cats\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n\r\nFor dogs, please fill out our \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/pre-adoption-form-dogs/\"\u003ePre-Adoption Questionnaire - Dogs\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n\r\nFor more information on our Adoption Process, please visit this \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/our-adoption-process/\"\u003elink\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n\r\nPlease make sure that you are familiar with our \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/adoption-agreement/\"\u003eAdoption Agreement\u003c/a\u003e as it has recently changed.\r\n\r\nFor more information on any of our animals, please \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/contact-us/\"\u003eContact Us\u003c/a\u003e.","age":"5 years 8 months","breeds":["Domestic Short Hair"],"breeds_display":"Domestic Short Hair","coat":"Short","contact_name":null,"contact_number":"08 6336 9410","contact_preferred_method":"Email","created_at":"2/9/2014 15:23","date_of_birth":"12/7/2012","desexed":true,"foster_needed":false,"gender":"Female","group":"Homeless and Abused Animal Rescue Team","heart_worm_treated":null,"id":316602,"interstate":false,"last_updated":"22/3/2018 9:40","medical_notes":"","microchip_number":"","mix":false,"multiple_animals":false,"name":"Whinney HC13-154","personality":"Whinney is an independent girl who likes lazing around the house, she's not bothered by other cats or dogs as long as they don't want to cuddle too much, then she will find her own alone space. \r\n\r\nShe will come up for the occasional cuddle but generally a cosy spot at the end of the bed or couch is all this beautiful girl craves :) \r\n\r\n** PLEASE NOTE: all HAART cats are to be adopted as indoor only cats for their safety and to comply with the legal requirements of the Cat Act. \r\nHAART recommends the use of Oscillot cat fencing or feline safe Catio's/portable caboodle to ensure they have access to the outdoors. \r\nPlease ask us for information on other suitable products **","photos":[{"small_80":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_80,w_80,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg","medium_130":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_130,w_130,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg","large_340":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_340,w_340,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg","xlarge_900":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_900,w_900,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg"},{"small_80":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_80,w_80,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg","medium_130":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_130,w_130,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg","large_340":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_340,w_340,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg","xlarge_900":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_900,w_900,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg"},{"small_80":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_80,w_80,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg","medium_130":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_130,w_130,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg","large_340":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_340,w_340,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg","xlarge_900":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_900,w_900,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg"}],"senior":false,"size":null,"species":"Cat","state":"WA","postcode":"6000","vaccinated":"Yes","wormed":"Yes"}
```

I want to grab the "adoption_process" and "personality" parts and using PHP break the lines when "\n" is in the output.

I have the following:

```
$adoption_process = {
  foreach ($line in explode("\n", $json['adoption_process']))
     {$line = trim($line);
    }
}
```

Then I'm using print_r to echo the output.  But it's not working.

Open to suggestions on other (better) ways to do this.

Comment: post the whole structure of the array

Comment: Have you decoded the JSON after getting response from API? use json_decode($json_response); Also you provided json is not valid it should contain ']}' at the end of json, then only it is valid json

Comment: Please define "not working".  What have you tried and _what were your results_ (specifically, beyond "not working")?

Comment: Please post a valid json string.

Comment: Please check json is valid json ? link - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Json is coming invalid.try to cross check the json what you are getting from API

Comment: Include your exact desired output in your question.  Voted Unclear.

Comment: @Black I have coded up a clean working solution and then temporarily deleted it.  When you improve/complete your question, I will make it available to you.  Answering incomplete/unclear questions is bad for StackOverflow, so I am doing what I believe is best for the community.

Answer (score -1):

The `JSON` you mention is invalid. It's not properly closed array at the end. I have copy the JSON and put changes. Just have look below, Hope it will help you out.

```
<?php 

$json = '{"listings":[{"adoption_fee":"$200","adoption_process":"For cats, please fill out our \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/pre-adoption-form-cats/\"\u003ePre-Adoption Questionnaire - Cats\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n\r\nFor dogs, please fill out our \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/pre-adoption-form-dogs/\"\u003ePre-Adoption Questionnaire - Dogs\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n\r\nFor more information on our Adoption Process, please visit this \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/our-adoption-process/\"\u003elink\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n\r\nPlease make sure that you are familiar with our \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/adoption-agreement/\"\u003eAdoption Agreement\u003c/a\u003e as it has recently changed.\r\n\r\nFor more information on any of our animals, please \u003ca href=\"http://www.haart.org.au/contact-us/\"\u003eContact Us\u003c/a\u003e.","age":"5 years 8 months","breeds":["Domestic Short Hair"],"breeds_display":"Domestic Short Hair","coat":"Short","contact_name":null,"contact_number":"08 6336 9410","contact_preferred_method":"Email","created_at":"2/9/2014 15:23","date_of_birth":"12/7/2012","desexed":true,"foster_needed":false,"gender":"Female","group":"Homeless and Abused Animal Rescue Team","heart_worm_treated":null,"id":316602,"interstate":false,"last_updated":"22/3/2018 9:40","medical_notes":"","microchip_number":"","mix":false,"multiple_animals":false,"name":"Whinney HC13-154","personality":"Whinney is an independent girl who likes lazing around the house, she\'s not bothered by other cats or dogs as long as they don\'t want to cuddle too much, then she will find her own alone space. \r\n\r\nShe will come up for the occasional cuddle but generally a cosy spot at the end of the bed or couch is all this beautiful girl craves :) \r\n\r\n** PLEASE NOTE: all HAART cats are to be adopted as indoor only cats for their safety and to comply with the legal requirements of the Cat Act. \r\nHAART recommends the use of Oscillot cat fencing or feline safe Catio\'s/portable caboodle to ensure they have access to the outdoors. \r\nPlease ask us for information on other suitable products **","photos":[{"small_80":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_80,w_80,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg","medium_130":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_130,w_130,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg","large_340":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_340,w_340,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg","xlarge_900":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_900,w_900,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_db5ee_orig.jpg"},{"small_80":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_80,w_80,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg","medium_130":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_130,w_130,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg","large_340":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_340,w_340,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg","xlarge_900":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_900,w_900,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_fb958_orig.jpg"},{"small_80":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_80,w_80,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg","medium_130":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_130,w_130,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg","large_340":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_340,w_340,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg","xlarge_900":"https://res.cloudinary.com/petrescue/image/upload/h_900,w_900,c_pad,q_auto:best/petrescue-production-s3/uploads/pet_photos/2014/9/2/316602_9030a_orig.jpg"}],"senior":false,"size":null,"species":"Cat","state":"WA","postcode":"6000","vaccinated":"Yes","wormed":"Yes"}]}';

$data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($data['listings'] as $key => $value){
    $process = explode("\n",$value['adoption_process']);
    foreach($process as $k => $v){
        if(trim($v)){
            $line[] = $v;
        }
    }
}

print_r($line);
```